# Yocto/poky on QEMU: Incoming SSH works but no internet

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, qemu, yocto

I am trying to debug a Linux system built with Yocto using QEMU. I run both Yocto and QEMU under Ubuntu 22.04 that I run using WSL. The image I am using is core-image-full-cmdline.

For some reason, network connection to the internet is not working, even though ifconfig shows that  eth0 is up and configured and I can connect to the system from WSL console using ssh. Trying to ping anything, be it a domain address or on ip, results in ping saying nothing.

I must be missing some configuration either in the host or the target system, but what could that be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this solved myself.

Googling revealed me that there has been a change from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04 in what software is used by default for configuring network. That led me to try Ubuntu 20.04 keeping everything else the same, and that fixed this issue.